# Bluetooth endpoint unregistered

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth, configuration, bluetooth-speaker

I am facing an issue when enabling Bluetooth on my Ubuntu system. I have tried a few commands to check my bluetooth status and also tried to fix it.

This is what I was getting when I run `sudo hciconfig -a hci0 up`

[image]

Also, when I checked my bluetooth status, it was showing active since 19th May but getting some **endpoint unregistered**

Comment: Please edit the question to include results from terminal for `lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net; lsusb; sudo dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'`

Comment: Please, no pictures of text. Here's how to paste from your terminal: https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/20164/